# MySQL query using unixtime

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to query a calls.csv table (below) to extract the total calls, total talk seconds and average call seconds:

- By day
- For the queue 24710 during the month of August 2015

```
Callid      Qid     Tm_init     Tm_disc
780164900   24710   1422835548  1422835559
780164901   24710   1422835562  1422835687
```

I arrived at the following query, however, I have been having some difficulties to write the query regarding 'by day' and 'queue 24710 during the month of August 2015':

```
SELECT 
(AVG(`Tm_disc` - `Tm_init`)) AS AVARAGE_CALLS_SECONDS,
(SUM(`Tm_disc` - `Tm_init`)) AS TOTAL_SECONDS_CALLS,
COUNT(`Callid`) AS TOTAL_NUMBER_CALLS
FROM
calls_database.`calls`
```

Any help, please?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Next time please take a minute to format your post and make it readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FROM_UNIXTIME() to convert unix date to timestamp and then regular datetime functions such as DATE() functions to extract day from the unixtime.

```
SELECT 
  (AVG(`Tm_disc` - `Tm_init`)) AS AVARAGE_CALLS_SECONDS,
  (SUM(`Tm_disc` - `Tm_init`)) AS TOTAL_SECONDS_CALLS,
  COUNT(`Callid`) AS TOTAL_NUMBER_CALLS
FROM
  calls
WHERE 
  Qid=24710
AND
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(Tm_init))=2
AND
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(Tm_init))=2015
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Tm_init))
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58dfcc8/9

Then add your filters such as Qid=1234.

Comment: Hi Anton. Many thanks for helping me with the query. However, the   "calls.csv" table has thousands of rows (26K rows) with severals 'Qid'. So, how woud be possible please narrow the query into "Queue 24710 during the month of August 2015"? Thank you!

Comment: Frank, I've updated the answer so it now filters by queue, month and year. Just change month to 8 (August) I used February (2) since that is what you have in your sample data.

Comment: Hi Anton. It worked very well. Many thanks for the support. Regards

Comment: Good to know it helped, Frank! Don't forget to accept the answer :)